# For some time, some of my pages do not display the content anymore. Any idea where this could be coming from?

Tags: php, theme-development, content

I recently worked on this website : https://semaine.com/
But since some time the content of the pages https://semaine.com/classroom/ and https://semaine.com/cinema/ are not displayed anymore.
The pages load, the navbar and the footer are there but not the content.
It works locally on my computer with MAMP but not online.
I tried several things like disabling various plugins, re-generating links, restoring the theme from my local version, ...
Here is the content of the cinema.php file:

```php
<?php 
/**
 * Template Name: cinema
 * description: cinema
 */
?> 

<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php 

  if($_GET && $_GET['categories']){

      $cat = $_GET['categories'];

    }

      // args
      $args = array(
        // 'numberposts' => -1,
        'posts_per_page'=> -1,
        'post_type'   => 'tastemakers_people',
        'category_name'  => $cat,
        'order'       => 'DESC',
      );

// query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );

?>

<div class="tastemakers_video">

 <div class="tastemakers_people_header styleBB" style="display:none;">
 <a class="header_all" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/">all/</a><a class="header_art" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=art">art/</a><a class="header_music" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=music">music/</a><a class="header_philosopy" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=philosophy">think/</a><a class="header_fashion" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=fashion">fashion/</a><a class="header_healthrx" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=healthrx">healthRx/</a><a class="header_cinema" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=cinema">cinema/</a><a class="header_food" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=food">food/</a><a class="header_business" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=business">business/</a><a class="header_lovesex" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>/cinema/?categories=love&sex">love&sex/</a>

  </div>

  <?php
    wp_nav_menu( array( 
      'theme_location' => 'menu-sub-nav-cinema', 
      'container_class' => 'sub-nav' 
      )
    ); 
  ?>
 

 <div class="cinema">

  

  <?php if( $the_query->have_posts() ): ?>
      <?php while( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post(); ?>
      
        <?php if( get_field('watch_copy') ): ?>
        
            <!-- <?php the_field('watch_copy'); ?> -->
            <div class="tastemaker_video_holder">
            <div class="video_intro"><?php the_field('watch_intro'); ?></div>
          
               <div class="video">


               <div class="video_holder"><iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php the_field('watch_copy'); ?>" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>

              </div>
            </div>

          

      <?php endif; ?>

     <?php endwhile; ?>  

     </div>  

   <?php else: 

    echo '<div class="error">Sorry. There is no content for this category</div>';


    ?>

    <?php endif; ?>
 

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Here is a part of the error_log file :

```
[26-May-2022 19:17:18 UTC] WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_options` made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Autoloader::Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\{closure}, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Plugins_Handler->cache_plugins, set_transient, update_option
[28-May-2022 08:00:54 UTC] WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:0:{}' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_jetpack_autoloader_plugin_paths' made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Autoloader::Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\{closure}, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Plugins_Handler->cache_plugins, set_transient, update_option
[28-May-2022 08:02:13 UTC] WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_options` made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Autoloader::Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\{closure}, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Plugins_Handler->cache_plugins, set_transient, update_option
[28-May-2022 08:04:11 UTC] WordPress database error Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now for query UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = 'a:1:{i:0;s:29:\"{{WP_PLUGIN_DIR}}/woocommerce\";}' WHERE `option_name` = '_transient_jetpack_autoloader_plugin_paths' made by shutdown_action_hook, do_action('shutdown'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Autoloader::Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\{closure}, Automattic\Jetpack\Autoloader\jpdb897b9c8e0c5079b17448f17a52683a\Plugins_Handler->cache_plugins, set_transient, update_option
[31-May-2022 10:34:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  ID was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, add_progress, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in /home/semainec/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5229
[31-May-2022 10:34:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  product_type was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart, do_action('woocommerce_external_add_to_cart'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_external_add_to_cart, WC_Product_External->single_add_to_cart_text, apply_filters('woocommerce_product_single_add_to_cart_text'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, {closure}, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 3.0.) in /home/semainec/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5229
[31-May-2022 10:34:43 UTC] PHP Notice:  product_type was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. Product properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product.php'), wc_get_template_part, load_template, require('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/content-single-product.php'), do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart, do_action('woocommerce_external_add_to_cart'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, woocommerce_external_add_to_cart, wc_get_template, include('/themes/Blank-Theme/woocommerce/single-product/add-to-cart/external.php'), do_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_Points_Rewards_Product->render_product_message, apply_filters('wc_points_rewards_single_product_message'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, {closure}, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Product->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong Plea in /home/semainec/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5229
[31-May-2022 10:35:58 UTC] PHP Notice:  wpdb::prepare was called <strong>incorrectly</strong>. The query only expected one placeholder, but an array of multiple placeholders was sent. Please see <a href="https://wordpress.org/support/article/debugging-in-wordpress/">Debugging in WordPress</a> for more information. (This message was added in version 4.9.0.) in /home/semainec/public_html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5229
```

Comment: when you say not the content, do you mean it prints `Sorry. There is no content for this category` or do you mean something else? Have you checked your PHP error log? I see that this page template relies heavily on ACF fields, are you sure that the ACF part is setup correctly and the same way at both ends? You might need to ask about this in an ACF community

Comment: Nothing is displayed even the message that there is no content in this category.
I checked the error_log file, there are a lot of errors since May 26th, before that it goes back to May 18th, so if there is something it must be in there but I don't see where it can come from.
I checked the ACF fields, nothing has changed and everything seems to match, locally it works fine :/
I post you the error_log

Comment: I see content on both the pages you cite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, it was really simple.
It was simply my pages that did not load the template by default. The cinema page was not loading cinema.php, I simply renamed cinema.php to page-cinema.php and it works again.